# Combine row and column name based on column value (python)

Tags: python

[image]

If I have above table, I would like to combine rowname + columnname if column value = 'Y'. How would I do it?

The end result should be a list: a = (10,11,2290,20,21)

I tried the following:

Create a new column:

```
df['haves'] = df.eq('Y').dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')

col= df[["haves"]]
row= df[["PromofactsID"]]

row_lol = row.values.tolist()
col_lol = col.values.tolist()
```

Then I want to combine row_lol and col_lol but the haves column becomes one string and not individual elements.

Pls advise, Thanks in advance!

Regards.

I tried to do it like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what should work for you:

```
final_list = list()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for (columnName, columnData) in row[1:].iteritems():
        if columnData == 'Y':
            final_list.append(row['ID']*10+int(columnName))
```

Input dataframe

```
    ID  0   1
0   1   Y   Y
1   229 Y   None
2   2   Y   Y
```

Output list

```
[10, 11, 2290, 20, 21]
```

Comment: Hi Vishakha, I should've mentioned, the column names are not in sequence, and there are a few columns so ideally I don't want to type it out line by line. Also, I don't want to replace the values, I need a separate list. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @user7800072 I have updated the answer to work for multiple column names and the output is now a list like you wanted. Does that solve your query?